# Allow only one session for user with firebase authentication

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to limit the number of sessions in web app written with node.js and with firebase auth. Upon user Sign In I want to terminate other sessions of this user (in other browsers). How can I do it? I found some code using google search:

```js
// Revoke all refresh tokens for a specified user for whatever reason.
// Retrieve the timestamp of the revocation, in seconds since the epoch.
getAuth()
  .revokeRefreshTokens(uid)
  .then(() => {
    return getAuth().getUser(uid);
  })
  .then((userRecord) => {
    return new Date(userRecord.tokensValidAfterTime).getTime() / 1000;
  })
  .then((timestamp) => {
    console.log(`Tokens revoked at: ${timestamp}`);
  });
```

However, I do not know how to import this function getAuth on server side, when I try to include `import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';` into firebase functions source, I get this error during `firebase deploy`: `Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error`.

I tried to include it on client side too. I use React. On client side the function getAuth exists, but I have another error: `getAuth(...).revokeRefreshTokens is not a function`.

Comment: Firebase doesn't have any feature to limit the number of devices a user can sign in on. The topics of how to implement this has been covered quite a few times before, so I recommend checking out those [answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+authentiation+limit+devices). Outside of that, the second error is correct: you can't revoke a refresh token (or ID token for that matter) on the client, but you can make the app forget about it by [signing the user out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#next_steps).

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't have any feature to limit the number of devices a user can sign in on. The topics of how to implement this has been covered quite a few times before, so I recommend checking out those [answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+authentiation+limit+devices). In the Firebase documentation, you may also want to look at [managing user sessions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions), specifically how to [track and detect ID token revocation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation).

Outside of that, the second error is correct: you can't revoke a refresh token (or ID token for that matter) on the client, but you can make the app forget about it by [signing the user out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#next_steps).

Comment: But the code in my message is copied from this page you gave URL to (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation), see section "Revoke refresh tokens"

Comment: I don't care about devices, I want to limit per browser, using cookies somehow. This is the web app, not android app.

Comment: #1) Yup, but that code requires an Admin SDK and is supposed to run in a trusted environment, not on an end-user device. If you've never used one of Firebase Admin SDKs before, read this to learn about their use and how to get started: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup #2) Firebase doesn't implement a maximum number of devices on any platform. You will need to detect the thing you want to limit on (e.g. device ID or tab ID) yourself, and then implement the limit on top of that.

Comment: But I do not know how to import this function. I have this:

import { auth } from 'firebase-functions';
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

// import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

and I receive error if I uncomment the last line